# Why won't sort() or unique() work with an int vector (C++)?

Tags: sorting, c++11, vector, stl, unique

sort() and unique() won't work with such a simple int vector.
Any suggestions are welcome.

```
std::vector<int>vec {33,25,11,44,22,20,12,33,59,87,23,53,26,44,26,97,22,32,44,43,44};
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());

int nr = 1;
std::cout << std::endl;
for (auto p = vec.begin(); p!=vec.end(); p++){
    std::cout << *p << " ";
    if (!(nr++%4)) std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

returns:

```
11 12 20 22
23 25 26 32
33 43 44 53
59 87 97 44
44 53 59 87
97 21
```

Note that the numbers are neither sorted, not duplicates are expelled  (I marked 44, 53).

**UPD: thanks to the contributors, here's the solution:
instead of

```
std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

we type:

```
    auto last = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());//returns an iterator to non-unique elements
    vec.erase(last, vec.end());// and kills them
```

Comment: Wow, it worked! Really!
So, what's changed is this:
`auto last = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());`
`vec.erase(last, vec.end());`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::sort` works fine. As for the `std::unique` - it doesn't alter the size of the vector, it just creates a subsequence at the beginning of the vector with a sequence of one copy of all distinct elements. So, as you indicated in your own comment - you need to keep the iterator [`std::unique`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) returns, and iterate from the beginning of the vector to that end iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `std::set` would be more beneficial.

you can just use the vector, sort + unique method

```
sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
vec.erase( unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end() );
```

you get this return instead

```
[1,10]      1.6821   
[1,1000]    5.0773  
[1,100000]  8.7955
```

Comment: Yes, set worked fine for me. It's very easy with a set.
This current exercise is for using a vector.